# How do you get Devanagari (Sanskrit देवनागरी) script on Google Slides?

Tags: google-drive, localization, google-slides

I need to do a presentation in Sanskrit on Google Slides but was not able to find the script. I looked at the inbuilt scripts in **File > Language** and Hindi, Nepali, Bengali, Malayalam etc were there, but not Sanskrit.

Does anyone know an easy way for me to be able to access a Sanskrit keyboard in Google Slides?

Comment: Just pick Hindi/Nepali/Marathi; they all use Devanagari. Or just use a Sanskrit input method (that works across all apps on your computer, not just Google Slides). Just curious, what is the presentation about? :-)

Comment: Thank you @ShreevatsaR but what’s a Sanskrit I put method? (Sorry I’ve never done this before!) This is actually for my grandmother who is taking a course in Sanskrit and has to make a presentation!